# A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I am doing financial calculator in c# using visual studio, I keep on getting error above and I can't seem to solve it, everything seems working except I keep on getting this exception when I break it is leading me to the thousand textbox.cs and the line below.

```
return Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

Comment: Well what is the value of `val` when it errors?

Comment: Apologise, edited it to show what line is getting the error.

Comment: well the exception is saying that the string is not in the correct format. What does val contain?

Comment: (local variable) string val

Comment: no, what actual value is in val, what does the debugger show val contains?

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails - read the manual (or google it)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

> FormatException:   value does not consist of an optional sign followed
>   by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Comment: Found the error....had thousandtextbox set to read only set to false instead of true.